# Select Option opens new Text Box

Tags: html, forms, select, textbox

I want to have a select option that opens a corresponding text box.

Let's say these are my selections:

```
<select id="contact">
  <option value="email">Email</option>
  <option value="phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

When you select the Email selection I want it to show a textbox below it (which wasn't there before) that says please enter your Email.

OR

When you select the Phone selection I want it  to show a textbox below it (which wasn't there before) that says please enter your Phone Number.

I don't want both the "Enter Email" and "Enter Phone Number" textboxes showing at the same time. I want them to select which one to open and input their contact info.

I currently have this but don't know what else to have in it... please help!

```
$('#contact').change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() === 'email') {
           //show email
           //hide phone

        } else {
            //hide email
           //show phone
        }
});
```

Thanks,
Chad.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Please check my edit above!!

Comment: @ChadCardiff: Didn't it work?

Comment: I found a way myself, check out my post below. Didn't see your post until I posted mine! (I still upped your post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, used the following javascript for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckContact(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('email');
 if(val=='email')
   element.style.display='block';
 else
   element.style.display='none';

 var element=document.getElementById('sms');
 if(val=='sms')
   element.style.display='block';
 else
   element.style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

Then had this in the form:

```
<select name="contactinfo" id="contactinfo" onchange="CheckContact(this.value);">
  <option>Select Contact Option</option>
  <option value="email">Email</option>
  <option value="sms">Text (SMS)</option>
</select><br />
<div id="email" style="display: none;">Enter Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br /></div>
<div id="sms" style="display: none;">Enter Cell Number: <input type="text" name="sms" /><br /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement and the solution is:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form name="myform">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other')   {this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else     {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```